# Multiple HDF5 files in single GDAL virtual raster

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal-merge, hdf5

Does anyone know how to generate a single GDAL virtual raster linking multiple HDF5 files to each other? Each file represents different swaths of the globe with different lat/lon coordinates and data bands.

For now, I'm generating a single .vrt file for each HDF5 file, then using gdal_merge to collect them all together. However, I would like to do this in one process. The idea being to link all the files to generate a single global map.

Comment: Have you tried [`gdalbuildvrt`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html)?

Comment: Adding to @Luke's comment: With `gdalbuildvrt` you can create VRTs containing VRTs. In other words in your current processing chain instead of using `gdal_merge` on the single-HDF5-VRTs use `gdalbuildvrt` to create a nested all-HDF5-VRT.

Comment: That seems like a good idea; thanks to both! I'll give it a try. A follow-up question: is there a way to merge all the VRT files such that they fall into a raster of a specific size? collectively, they should be a global map with known rows and columns.